# How to do a subquery on the same table by using JPA Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager, hibernate-criteria

Help me to convert the below mentioned query to Hibernate JPA.
Query query= entityManager.createQuery("Select a,b,c,d from table1 where d IN (Select d from table1 where a=1 and b=2");

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just giving an alias should work

```
entityManager.createQuery("Select a,b,c,d from table1 t
 where t.d IN (Select r.d from table1 r where r.a=1 and r.b=2");
```

Comment: Thank you Asgar.
Can we update the query using criteria

Comment: Yes, you can. You can work that out